# UITableView deselectRowAtIndexPath calling UITableviewCell setSelected?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have custom cells that perform a short animation when selected and should animate back to their first state when deselected.

Here is me `setSelected`

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

if (selected && animated) {
    NSLog(@"animate");
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         self.chevronImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
                         [self.chevronImage setCenter:CGPointMake(self.chevronImage.center.x, self.chevronImage.center.y - 1)];
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}

if (!selected && animated) {
    NSLog(@"unanimate");
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         self.chevronImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
                         [self.chevronImage setCenter:CGPointMake(self.chevronImage.center.x, self.chevronImage.center.y + 1)];
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}

[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}
```

And here is the code that calls it:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (![selectedIndex isEqual:indexPath]) {
    NSLog(@"select %i", indexPath.row);
    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
if (selectedIndex != nil) {
    NSLog(@"deselect %i", selectedIndex.row);
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndex animated:YES];
}
if (controlRowIndex != nil && [indexPath isEqual:controlRowIndex]) {
    return;
}

indexPath = [self modelIndexPathforIndexPath:indexPath];
NSIndexPath *indexPathToDelete = controlRowIndex;

if ([indexPath isEqual:selectedIndex]){
    selectedIndex = nil;
    controlRowIndex = nil;
} else {
    selectedIndex = indexPath;
    controlRowIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1
                                         inSection:indexPath.section];
}

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
if (indexPathToDelete){
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathToDelete]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
if (controlRowIndex){
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[controlRowIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
[self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

This works fine if I select a row and then tap on it again to deselect it. However, if I tap on row 0 and then tap on row 1 I get both rows selected, row 0 never gets deselected.

I can't figure what's different, I'm passing the exact same value each time, but I can only get it to animate if it's also currently selected. I've verified that it's sending the correct indexPath so I'm at a bit of a loss.

EDIT: Added the full method code

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE. Same for the [tag:objective-c] tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would have expected that you set the variable `selectedIndex` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, but I cannot see where you are setting it. Thus, it looks like you are comparing to the wrong index path.

Conceptionally, I would first do the deselection.

```
BOOL tappedSelectedCell = [selectedIndex isEqual:indexPath];
if (selectedIndex != nil) {
   // deselect selectedIndex
   selectedIndex = nil;
}

if (selectedIndex == nil && !tappedSelectedCell) {
   // select indexPath
   selectedIndex = indexPath;
}
```

or simpler, but slightly longer

```
if (selectedIndex == nil) {
   // select indexPath
   selectedIndex = indexPath;
   return;
}

if ([selectedIndex isEqual:indexPath]) {
   // deselect indexPath
   selectedIndex = nil;
}
else {
    // deselect selectedIndex
    // select indexPath
    selectedIndex = indexPath;
}
```

Comment: I do actually set it in there, I just didn't post the entire method because it does a lot of stuff that doesn't apply to my question (I insert an extra row below the one selected). I'll edit to show the entire method.